# Excel - Want to compare a projected date against a target date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

In Excel, I am trying to compare a forecast date against a target date and state in the 3rd column the difference, I have searched for a formula to put in the 3rd column such as DATEDIF (F5, G5,"m") but this is not able to state the difference if the projected date is less than the target date,

Please see example below:

EXCHANGE Target Date    EXCHANGE Forecast Date  EXCHANGE Difference
01/12/2018           11/01/2019               1
01/08/2017           16/02/2019               18
02/08/2017           01/06/2017              #NUM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some Error handling, if the date is in the past, flip the calculation and multiply it by -1 or subtract it from 0. It's annoying that the function doesn't handle this itself but oh well...

`IFERROR(DATEDIF(F5,G5,"m"),DATEDIF(G5,F5,"m")*-1)`

`IFERROR(DATEDIF(F5,G5,"m"),0-DATEDIF(G5,F5,"m"))`

**EDIT:**

To evaluate weeks you would use the same function but taking the difference in days, you can then divide the result by 7 (make use of the `ROUND()` function if you don't want a decimal answer)

`IFERROR(DATEDIF(F5,G5,"D")/7,0-DATEDIF(G5,F5,"D")/7)`

`IFERROR(ROUND(DATEDIF(F5,G5,"D")/7,0),ROUND(0-DATEDIF(G5,F5,"D")/7,0))`

Comment: I think using IFERROR is a good idea. =SIGN(G5-F5)*DATEDIF(MIN(F5,G5),MAX(F5,G5),"m") would be an alternative but as it doesn't have any particular advantage I haven't posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - the issue is that my manager wants a template with the formula in place so that when people enter their projected dates, they can view whether someone is on target or not (and by how many/weeks/months etc).  From what you have said, I am assuming this can't be done as there is no formula that will counter for both ahead or behind the target date (only if I enter the formula as we go which defeats the purpose of the spreadsheet template).

Comment: @TJB333 Well the formula provided will give you the desired result as if the date is in the past it will proceed to the flipped results and multiply by -1 so you get the same difference but negative... For project management I would advise a GANTT chart and a Kanban board, they make it easy to visualise project progression.

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much.  The formula provides exactly what I need.

Comment: @TJB333 Glad to be of help, if this solves you issue, please mark the answer as accepted by using the tick to the left... thank you.

Comment: Thanks - just one more thing.  Is there a way to adjust the formula to measure in weeks rather than months?