# IF Formula to compare a date to a nominated date in the future in excel

Tags: date, if-statement, excel-formula

In one cell I want a date ie: 31/03/21
I want the formula to be able to check that date and when it is X years so 31/03/2023 it can either colour code the box or mark as overdue
I've seen this answer:
[Excel - Want to compare a projected date against a target date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059425/excel-want-to-compare-a-projected-date-against-a-target-date)

But, this would mean we would have to put in the sheet for 1 year 365 days, 2 years - 730 days e.t.c . Is that the only way to do it or can you do some way for just year, two years etc...?

For some context, I work for a volunteer organization and all volunteers have to do various trainings every X amount of years. So, looking for an easy way to put them on a sheet with the training and have it colour change/highlight/mark as overdue when they come up every few years or so.

Much thanks

Comment: maybe use a screenshot to demonstrate your problem and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional formatting to achieve the result

[image: sample data and result]

Select all cells with dates, goto Conditional formatting, create new rule as below

[image: Formula]

Enter the formula

```
=TODAY()-A2>=(B2*365)
```

This should get you the result